# How to make this method generic? Converting RelativeLayout into Bitmap Image

Tags: android, generics, android-layout, bitmap, converters

I have wrote a method to convert any layout Liner,Relative,Frame etc into Bitmap but I want to make this method generic so that it accepts `android.view.ViewGroup` as a parameter rather than specific `Relative` or `LinearLayout`.

**Here is my method below:**

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(RelativeLayout v) {
        v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: changing v.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); into v.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Layout's inherit from `ViewGroup`, so you can use `ViewGroup` as method parameter and all those statements will works fine.

Also you should use  `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` instead of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` to make it generic.

Comment: When to use wild cards in methods then ?

Comment: What do you mean by wildcards? If you are referring towards generics or templates, it is not necessary here, since inheritance and polymorphism can do the job.